# Problem Installing EVGA GTX 760 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

i have been trying to installing a NVIDIA GTX760 on a Ubuntu 14.04, but i can´t get any image from the video card, so i am using the vga from the mother board, 
and i have been trying to install the .run (nvidia-325)

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-325

(dont work)

from the nvidia page but it dont work out, do you know how can i get fix this and by the way shoud i install cuda 5.5 or cuda 6 , i have read that cuda 6 is not well supported in ubuntu 14.04, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on this site: http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.32-driver

Maybe this can also help you:http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-nvidia-319-32-drivers-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-and-linux-mint-15-14-13/

Answer (score 0):

i tried that don't work , i could get install the nvidia 331, and nvidia-prime, but i couldn't get graphics from my nvidia card, just from the motherboard, and the nvidia X server appears as a programa but just don't open , well and i tried to install cuda 6 , a error appears, i also tried nvidia-cuda-toolkit, but this don't work , i am going to try with lubuntu 13.10 in order to maybe install cuda 6, this idea is in order to install gromacs, and that uses this GPU